# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Currently, I am working on an old project and I met too many errors, my goal is to succeed the deployment on my local machine, Brief in this below class, the **GetHelpPageSampleGenerator()** is underlined in red:

```
 public static class HelpPageConfigurationExtensions
{
    private const string ApiModelPrefix = "MS_HelpPageApiModel_";



    public static void SetSampleObjects(this HttpConfiguration config, IDictionary<Type, object> sampleObjects)
    {
        config.GetHelpPageSampleGenerator().SampleObjects = sampleObjects;
    }
```

In the same classe i have the method GetHelpPageSampleGenerator() but overload, it means that the method SetSampleObjects  and by using config argument which i can't understand it calls GetHelpPageSampleGenerator()   :

```
 public static HelpPageSampleGenerator GetHelpPageSampleGenerator(this HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            return (HelpPageSampleGenerator)config.Properties.GetOrAdd(
                typeof(HelpPageSampleGenerator),
                k => new HelpPageSampleGenerator());
        }
```

the error that i get:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'WebInstructionSheet.Areas.HelpPage.HelpPageConfigurationExtensions.GetHelpPageSampleGenerator(System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration)'
>   and
>   'WebInstructionSheet.Areas.HelpPage.HelpPageConfigurationExtensions.GetHelpPageSampleGenerator(System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration)'

Comment: It seems this happens to folks when there is a reference in source AND a reference to the binary. Have you tried cleaning your cache (obj, bin) folders? Also check your references.

Comment: No, but i only cleaned the project and rebuild it but same.

Comment: Those are `Extension methods`, you can search and understand more about it.And as @MikeCheel suggested, delete obj, bin directories from project and build again.

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening after compiling the project in memory, I do not really know what the exact cause of this error is. If it was not a bug, then it is differently misleading message.
I tried cleaning the solution and manually deleting the obj/bin folders but that didn't solve the issue.
Try deleting or commenting out the code that is causing this ambiguity to the code generator and then add it back again after you get all the code generated for you. This is just a work around, as long as the error message you are getting indicates the exact line of code of confusion.
If that does not solve your issue directly, it will at least give you a more meaningful message where you can move forward.
**In my case, I let it create a new DbContext and create all the controllers and views I wanted then I got rid of the newly generated context and used mine.**
Following the wisdom: *If it does not give you what you want, give it what it needs* :)